# How to solve issue of PendingDeprecationWarning: the matrix subclass is not the recommended way to represent matrices

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matrix, scipy, deprecated

I am using a python code as a black box that I do not want to touch. The code was working well using Python under Ubuntu 12.04 but after upgrading the system to Ubuntu 16, I got the below warning which interrupt the code from running. Any idea how I can fix this without changing the code? Many thanks.

> File "/home/hammouc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 849, in todense
>       return np.asmatrix(self.toarray(order=order, out=out))
>
> File "/home/hammouc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 71, in asmatrix
>       return matrix(data, dtype=dtype, copy=False)
>
> File "/home/hammouc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 123, in **new**
>       PendingDeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
>
> PendingDeprecationWarning: the matrix subclass is not the recommended way to represent matrices or deal with linear algebra (see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html). Please adjust your code to use regular ndarray.

Comment: Looks like a scipy.sparse matrix `todense` is triggering this.  The ideal is to replace this with a `toarray` method call.

Comment: Many thanks this helps!

Comment: Which `numpy` and `scipy` versions are you using?   I know we discourage the use of `np.matrix`, but I wasn't aware of any actual move toward deprecation.

Comment: I found that warning message in the np.matrixlib.defmatrix.py file (1.16.3).  Your warnings level must be different than mine (default).

Answer (score 2):

With the `import warnings` module, it's possible to control the display of warnings.

With `M` as a sparse matrix:

```
In [26]: warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=PendingDeprecationWarning)  
In [27]: M.todense()                                                            
Out[27]: 
matrix([[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.]])
In [28]: warnings.filterwarnings('default', category=PendingDeprecationWarning) 
In [29]: M.todense()                                                            
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py:71: PendingDeprecationWarning: the matrix subclass is not the recommended way to represent matrices or deal with linear algebra (see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html). Please adjust your code to use regular ndarray.
  return matrix(data, dtype=dtype, copy=False)
Out[29]: 
matrix([[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.]])
```

Producing a `ndarray` instead of a `np.matrix`:

```
In [30]: M.toarray()                                                            
Out[30]: 
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
In [31]: M.A                                                                    
Out[31]: 
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

Apparently my default `ipython` setup ignores these warnings, so I haven't seen this before.  I'll have to look at the config file.

Answer (score 0):

It is a pending deprecation warning.

**Meaning:** in one of the next versions this functionality will be taken out and your will crash after that.

It is a *WARNING* - currently your code will work, next update: who knows?

If you do not want to touch the code that uses the deprecated parts you have few options: 
- you can stop upgrading (freeze your Scipy version - never to upgrade again)
- you can change the code to use `ndarray`

Whatever path you take should probably be done after some reading into   https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) and making a **risk analysis** - if you use the code to do linear algrebra to land the next *Rover III* on *Saturn*, you should probably change it to something more reliable.

If you solve "watering" problems for your 3 tomatoe plants - worst things happening is you not going to get tomatoes and you have to buy them in a shop...